# How to make a indirect relation between two or more instances in Protégé

Tags: properties, ontology, protege

First of all, my English is poor, so sorry if my writing is confusing.

I'm trying to create the following relationship between instances: if `A propertyX B`, and `C propertyY A`, then `C propertyX B`. In my case, I want to specify that if a `ManagerA` "manages" an employee, and `ManagerB` has the same job as `ManagerA`, then he also manages the same employee.

I tried to use chain properties to do that, but the reasoner (FaCT ++ 1.6.5) doesn't work when I activate it (the log says a non-simple property is being used as one). I think the problem is in the fact that the property "manages" is asymmetric and irreflexive and the property "sameJob" is transitive and symmetric, but I'm not sure if that's the case. I applied the chain property in the "manages" property, stating: `sameJob o manages SubPropertyOf: manages`.

I'm just starting with Protégé and will appreciate any help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is due to `manages` not being a simple role, i.e. if you have `r1 o ... o rn subPropertyOf r` where n>1 then `r` is a non-simple role. Non-simple roles cannot be used in `IrreflexiveObjectProperty` and `AsymmetricObjectProperty`. See section 11 of [OWL 2 syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/). The reason for the constraint on roles is to maintain decidability.

However, you can achieve the desired result by adding a SWRL rule:

`manages(?x, ?y) ^ sameJob(?x, ?z) -> manages(?z, ?y)`.